# How to read Passport data with NFC Tag

Tags: react-native, nfc

Trying to implement passport reader.

I'm using library below:

https://github.com/whitedogg13/react-native-nfc-manager/blob/master/example/AppV2Apdu.js

But couldn't understand, which data I must send to "sendCommandAPDUIOS" for reading name, surname, cardid etc. datas.

IsoDep method always returns non-readable responses like "{response: [], sw1: 106, sw2: 136}"

There's not enough documentation about "what means custom APDU number and how to generate it".